# tftp options put option doesn't upload the file

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, tftp

I am using tftp to upload a file to a tftp server on my pc using the ubuntu subsystem on windows 10.

When I type a command like this:

> tftp -m binary 192.168.1.166 -c put someFileName

It doesn't upload the file. Instead the tftp prompt is invoked. And I have to type binary, connect, put under the tftp prompts. Much more typing.

Just wonder if anyone else has run into this issue.

Comment: Any chance there's an alias getting in the way?

Comment: Thank you NotTheDr01ds. I checked my .bashrc file and saw a few alias statements. But didn't see anything related to tftp. Maybe this is caused by the tftp package in the ubuntu subsystem. maybe I should install some other tftp tool.

Answer (score 1):

I installed tftp-hpa client in the ubuntu subsystem and now the -m -c options get recognized and I can do an upload in one command line.

Below is the link I followed to install the new tftp client:
https://linuxhint.com/install_tftp_server_ubuntu/

Thanks to NotTheDr01ds. Your comment got me thinking...